# Querying MySQL using a set of values in a JavaScript array

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I would like to submit a MySQL query that can be described something like "return all values from * if the id column matches any of the values in some array x."

Is there any way to use the entire contents of an array in a query in this way?

Comment: @Adshi yes this would be in NodeJS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var ids = [3, 4, 6, 8];
var query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (' + ids.join() + ')';
```

Now `query` contains query that will return all rows with id that matches any of the value in `ids` array.

With [mysql package](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) you can issue this query like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'admin',
  password : 'password'
});

// construct query
var ids = [3, 4, 6, 8];
var query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (' + ids.join() + ')';

connection.connect();

connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(rows) // log all matching rows.
});
```

Comment: What if it's more than one field? e.g. id and name.

Comment: It doesn't work if ids were strings and had spaces in between

Comment: Also, you should use escaping with '?' (question marks) https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `implode` function in PHP to take an array and transform it into a string separated by commas like this:

> "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id IN (" . implode(',',
>   $array_of_user_ids) . ")"

This is assuming that your array looks like `$array_of_user_ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, ...)`.

EDIT: My apologies, I didn't see the part about this being a JavaScript array. Adshi has your answer.

Comment: This question is asking under NodeJS environment